# What does "evaluated directly for a Boolean result, and no smartmatching occurs" in "Programming Perl" mean?

Tags: perl, boolean

In the "Programming Perl" book there is a snippet (cutted):

> By default, when(EXPR) is treated as an implicit smartmatch of `$_;` that is, `$_ ~~ EXPR`. However, if the EXPR argument to when is one of the 10 exceptional forms listed below,
>   it is evaluated directly for a Boolean result, and no smartmatching occurs:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. A regular expression match in the form of /REGEX/, $foo =~ /REGEX/, or $foo
>      =~ EXPR.

What does it mean `evaluated directly for a Boolean result`?

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
my @a = ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');

given(@a) {
    when (/a/) { say '@a contains an a'; }
    default    { say '@a does not contain an a' }
}
```

when I run it the output varies from time to time:

```
@a does not contain an a

@a contains an a

@a does not contain an a

@a does not contain an a
```

I can't understand what happens here, can anyone be so pleasant to help?

Appreciation in advance.

Comment: That's why smartmatch is evil.

Comment: But the book states that there is no smartmatch in that case

Comment: Chapter 4, section "The when Statement and Modifier", p.137

Comment: That's the new edition, right? I only have the 3rd. :(

Comment: Yes, that is the 4th one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read the documentation carefully:

> Another useful shortcut is that, if you use a literal array or hash as
>   the argument to "given", it is turned into a reference. So
>   "given(@foo)" is the same as "given(\@foo)", for example.

Therefore, `given (@a)` is turned into `given(\@a)`. There is no smart matching, because you use `when (/a/)`, so you are trying to match

```
\@a =~ /a/
```

The reference is stringified. It sometimes contains "a", as in `ARRAY(0x9a4e7f8)`, but usually does not :-)

Comment: Use `given(@a) { default { say $_; } }` to see what the value is that `given` evaluates.

Comment: The referencing is not the problem, it's not like `@a =~ /a/` would have been more sensible. The problem is that it doesn't do smartmatching, hence it doesn't distribute over the array.

Comment: @LeonTimmermans: The referencing explains why the result is different for different runs of the script.

Comment: True, but it doesn't explain why it's matched against the stringified regexp in the first place. It's missing step one.

Answer (score 5):

The documentatiom means that `when (/a/)` isn't equivalent to `if ($_ ~~ /a/)`, which would check to see if *any* of the array elements matched the regex, but to `if ($_ =~ /a/)`, which simply checks whether the scalar `$_` matches.

When you pass an array to `given` it assigns a *reference* to that array. And because (as the documentation says) the smart match operator isn't being used, a condition like `when (/a/)` is equivalent to `\@a =~ /a/`.

Because the reference will be stringified before the regex match is attempted, it will be comparing something like `ARRAY(0x61c6dc)`. Since you are looking for a lower-case `a` in the string, this will be true if the hex array location inside the string happens to contain an `a`. Not at all what you wanted!

Answer (score 4):

`when(/a/)` really does something like `if (/a/)`, not like `if ($_ ~~ /a/)`. If you want the latter, you should use `when (qr/a/)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
when ('a')
when (123)
```

is short for

```
when ($_ ~~ 'a')
when ($_ ~~ 123)
```

That list are exceptions to that behaviour. The one you're specifically asking about means

```
when (/b/)
when ($x =~ /c/)
```

is NOT short for

```
when ($_ ~~ /b/)
when ($_ ~~ $x =~ /c/)
```

They have their normal (outside of `when`) meaning, which is

```
when ($_ =~ /b/)
when ($x =~ /c/)
```